# Unable to access value of global variable in functions other than it is initialized

Tags: python

I have a written python code for real time system in which I am acquiring the data from one functions and assigning it to a variable which is actually a global variable but when I tried to use it in other functions I am unable to get updated value in other functions. How to get rid of this problem. Sample code which will give an elaborate idea what I am exactly doing is as follows.

```
obtained_value = 0 

### Inside the continuous loop statement ###
def Startloop(self):
    global obtained_value
    obtained_value = acquire_data()  ## obtained value is getting updated after every 0.25 seconds ##
    ## other statements ##

def some_functions(self):
    ### want to do something which depend on value ###
    print obtained_value             ## does not print value inside "obtained_value"
    val1 = obtained_value * 10
    print val1
    ## etc etc ###
```

I am not getting any value printed corresponding to print statement inside the some_function. Its seems like value of global variable is not getting updated. How to fix this problem. Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you using `global`? See http://stackoverflow.com/q/19158339/3001761

Comment: what is a `acquire_data()` returning? print it out

Comment: uhm... I just noticed your functions really look like methods. If so, then where is `obtained_value` declared? within the class? If that is the case, you should refer to it with `self.obtained_value`. And there is no need to declare it `global`, of course.

Comment: Actually it contains some decimal value and based on that value I have to  check and test some important conditions of my system.

Comment: OK. Please answer my questions regarding you functions/methods and I might be able to help you. Are the functions above part of a class? If so, they are methods and there is no need for global. You then need to decide if `obtain_value` is going to be a class variable or an object (class instance) variable.

Comment: I realise I still cannot get rid of C parlance. In my prev comment, "where is obtained_value declared?" I should have written "where is obtained_value first assigned?". In python there's no declaration. It's where you assign variables that matters. Just one of those little things..

Comment: All other functions are part of the same class except the function which is returning me the acquired value i.e acquire_data().

Comment: I have assigned it first time inside the Startloop function itself.

Comment: OK. I'd go for the instance variable, second option in my answer below. It depends on how you are going to use the class/objects.

Comment: Also note: if `obtained_value` is not an integer, you should initialise it to a constant of the proper type (e.g. `obtained_value = 0.0`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then it appears `Startloop` and `some_functions` are instance methods, let's say of class Xyz.

If you want `obtained_value` to be a class variable, which is shared among the objects (instances) of the class, then assign it first within the class:

```
class Xyz(object):
    obtained_value = 0.0

    def Startloop(self):
        self.obtained_value = acquire_data()  ## obtained value is getting...
        ## other statements ##

    def some_functions(self):
        ### want to do something which depend on value ###
        print self.obtained_value             ## does not print value...
        val1 = self.obtained_value * 10
        print val1
```

Otherwise, if you want `obtained_value` to be an object variable, which belongs to a specific object (instance) of the class, then assign it in its constructor:

```
class Xyz(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.obtained_value = 0.0

    def Startloop(self):
        self.obtained_value = acquire_data()  ## obtained value is getting...
        ## other statements ##

    def some_functions(self):
        ### want to do something which depend on value ###
        print self.obtained_value             ## does not print value...
        val1 = self.obtained_value * 10
        print val1
```

The key point is that Python has the concept of namespaces (please read on, don't be scared!)
In the first case, `obtained_value` is assigned to the class' namespace.
In the second case, `obtained_value` is assigned to the object's namespace.
`obtained_value` is simply a name that is added to the appropriate namespace.

As you can see, `obtained_value` is reached the same way in both cases, through `self.obtained_value`. That is because Python looks for `obtained_value` in the object's namespace. If it does not find it there, Python looks for it in the namespace of the object's class.

This answer is by no means exhaustive, but I hope it helps.
In case, please see the official [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html).

Comment: I have tried the way you have suggested in this reply. But none of them is giving me gives me any value. Even the "print self.obtained_value" statement inside the function "some_functions(self)" do not print any value on terminal. Is their any other way to get updated value in "some_functions(self)" function.

Comment: please post some more code. How you use the class, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Read these two lines again:

```
global value
obtained_value = acquire_data()
```

Spoiler:

```
value != obtained_value
```

Comment: Firstly thank you for replying and extremely sorry for mistake that I have committed while my post. I have edited my question. Please give your valuable suggestion for the corrected post.