# pytest test class calling class methods, Type error takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I have a test class to test my methods but i have some issue with passing self, both of them are inside class and test class.

my method:

```
def get_all_links(self):
    """return all the links inside an html

    :return: list of links from an html page
    :rtype: list
    """
    return self.html.find_all('a')
```

my test case:

```
    @parameterized.expand(["http://www.google.com", "http://www.walla.com"])
    def test_get_all_links_known_links(self, known_link):
        """check get_all_links with a known link list

        :param known_link: lick to find
        :type known_link: str
        """
        html = Parser(open(os.path.normpath(os.path.join(self.root, "test.html"))))

        self.assertTrue(any([known_link in str(l) for l in html.get_all_links()]))
```

error:

```
E TypeError: test_get_all_links_known_links() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/unittest/case.py:329: TypeError
...
```

Comment: Actually; are you using [nose](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) or pytest? You question title implies [pytest](https://pytest.org) -- Even your tag includes ``pytest``. -- Which is it?

Comment: @James Mills I am using pytest but trying to use nose parameterized with it.

Comment: No; use pytest's parameterization and fixtures :) Please! Don't over complicated things be mixing two test frameworks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *really* don't need to subclass `unittest.TestCase` here:

You can also "parametize" tests using [pytest](https://pytest.org) as well:

**Example:**

```
import pytest


from app.objects import Root  # Example


known_links = [
    "http://www.google.com",
     "http://www.walla.com"
]


@pytest.fixture()
def root(request):
    return Root()  # Root object


@pytest.mark.parametrize("known_links", known_links)
def test_get_all_links_known_links(root, known_link):
    html = Parser(
        open(os.path.normpath(os.path.join(root, "test.html")))
    )

    assert any([known_link in str(l) for l in html.get_all_links()])
```

See:

- [pytest: Fixtures: explicit, modular, scalable](https://pytest.org/latest/fixture.html)
- [pytest: Parametrizing tests](https://pytest.org/latest/example/parametrize.html)

Answer (score 2):

You need to import `parameterized` before using the decorator:

```
from nose_parameterized import parameterized
```

Comment: Oh haha I didn't notice the OP was using node and not pytest :) Whoops! Hmm actually I'm not sure now :)

Comment: Yea, although, he could actually be using both nose and unittest.  Check out these examples:  https://github.com/wolever/nose-parameterized

Comment: Oh well *shrug*; the OP hasn't responded ot our comments so let's call it *two possible solutions*) :)

Comment: @chown i am importing parameterized, but no i see the point, cant py.test use nose_parameterized?

Comment: @KobiK I'm not positive if it works with py.test or not.  I've only seen it done with unittest.  Check out that link above in my previous comment.  It gives lots of usage examples for nose_parameterizes with unittest.

Comment: I've tried it, same error i'm using it inside a class probably some stupid error.

Answer (score 0):

add `self.` in front of `html.get_all_links`

```
self.assertTrue(any([known_link in str(l) for l in self.html.get_all_links()]))
```

Python must be able to find the method in the namespace. Through self (i.e. your object instance) it can find all entries in the instance namespace and all entries in its class namespace, etc.
See [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html) for info regarding classes/methods/attributes/namespaces.
Also see my answer to a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29702149/unable-to-access-value-of-global-variable-in-functions-other-than-it-is-initiali/29703345#29703345)

Comment: There is no ``self.html`` in the above sample code.

Comment: Your "edit" is really no better IHMO and confusing. At least show an example of *what could happen*.